# I can't upload photo that get another api to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, firebase-storage, android-glide

I created basic android screen with listing popular movies(THE MOVIE DB)`enter code here`.I am using recyclerview to do this.When I click up the movie,I see the details about that film.Everything is okey until the here.My main purpose is uploading the movie poster in firebase.My connection has been done.I can write movie name,rating and overview but I can't upload the movie poster in firebase.Are there any person that can help me? Thank you

```
public class MyMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMovieAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Movie> mList;
public static String movieId;
public Glide x;


private DatabaseReference dRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference rootRef=dRef.child("user");
private StorageReference storageManager;


public MyMovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> mList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mList = mList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyMovieAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.movie_layout,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyMovieAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) { //final
    holder.title.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());
    String vote=Double.toString(mList.get(position).getVoteAverage());
    holder.uservote.setText(vote);

    Glide.with(context).load(mList.get(position).getImagePath()).into(holder.image);//placeholder?
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title,uservote;
    public ImageView image;

    MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        title=view.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        uservote=view.findViewById(R.id.movie_rate);
        image=view.findViewById(R.id.movie_image_2);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int pos=getAdapterPosition();
                //if line
                Movie selectedMovie=mList.get(pos);
                Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("original_title",mList.get(pos).getTitle());
                i.putExtra("poster_path",mList.get(pos).getImagePath());
                i.putExtra("overview",mList.get(pos).getOverView());
                i.putExtra("vote_average",Double.toString(mList.get(pos).getVoteAverage()));
                i.putExtra("release_date",mList.get(pos).getReleaseDate());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                movieId=dRef.push().getKey();

                rootRef.child(movieId).child("movieName").setValue(mList.get(pos).getTitle());
                rootRef.child(movieId).child("movieImage").setValue(mList.get(pos).getImagePath());
                //storageManager.child(mList.get(pos).getImagePath());
                storageManager=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


                 Uri u=Uri.parse(mList.get(pos).getImagePath());



                storageManager.putFile(u).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    }
                });

                context.startActivity(i);


            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView movieName,movieOverView,movieReleaseDate,movieUserAverage;
public ImageView imageView;
private Uri imageUri;

private DatabaseReference dRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference rootRef=dRef.child("user");
private StorageReference storageManager= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("upload").child("eee");

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie_content_detail_layout);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
    movieName=findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
    movieOverView=findViewById(R.id.movie_overview);
    movieReleaseDate=findViewById(R.id.movie_release_date);
    movieUserAverage=findViewById(R.id.movie_vote_average);

    Intent comenIntent=getIntent();

    if(comenIntent.hasExtra("original_title")){

        String nameOfMovie=getIntent().getExtras().getString("original_title");
        String overView=getIntent().getExtras().getString("overview");
        String vote=getIntent().getExtras().getString("vote_average");
        String releaseDate=getIntent().getExtras().getString("release_date");
        String image=getIntent().getExtras().getString("poster_path");

        Glide.with(this).load(image).into(imageView);
        movieName.setText(nameOfMovie);
        movieOverView.setText(overView);
        movieUserAverage.setText(vote);
        movieReleaseDate.setText(releaseDate);

        //StorageReference st=storageManager.child("fff");

        //selectImage();

        imageUri=Uri.parse(image);
        //getFileExtension(imageUri);

        storageManager.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });


    }
}

private void selectImage(){
    Intent b=new Intent();
    b.setType("image/*");
    b.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(b,RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        imageUri=data.getData();
    }

}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver cR=getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyMovieAdapter myMovieAdapter;
private ArrayList<Movie> movieList;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editScreen();
    swipeRefreshLayout=findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            editScreen();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Movies Refreshed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public Activity getActivity(){
   Context context=this;
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper){
       if (context instanceof Activity){
            return (Activity) context;
        }
        context=((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;
}

private void editScreen(){

    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Movies are being refreshed !");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);


    movieList=new ArrayList<>();
    myMovieAdapter=new MyMovieAdapter(this,movieList);

    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
    //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
   if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    }else{
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,4));
    }

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myMovieAdapter);
    myMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    loadJSON();

}

private void loadJSON(){



    try{

        if (BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Empty API KEY",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return;
        }

        Client client=new Client();
        Service apiService=client.getClient().create(Service.class);

        Call <MovieGetting> call=apiService.getPopularMovies(BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieGetting>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieGetting> call, Response<MovieGetting> response) {

               // Log.v("RESPONSE_CALLED", "ON_RESPONSE_CALLED");

                List<Movie> movies=response.body().getResults();

                //if(response.body().getResults()==null){
                  //  Log.v("RESPONSE_CALLED", "ON_RESPONSE_NULL");
               // }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyMovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),movies));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

                if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieGetting> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Empty API KEY",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.androidSettings:
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void selectImage(){
    Intent b=new Intent();
    b.setType("image/*");
    b.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(b,RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

```
public class Client {

public  static final String BASE_URL="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
public static Retrofit retrofit=null;

public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if (retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().
                baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

public interface Service {

```
@GET("movie/popular")
Call<MovieGetting> getPopularMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

}

```
public class Movie {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String overView;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    private String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String imagePath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    private Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("video")
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    private List<Integer>genreIds=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private Double voteAverage;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdropPath;

    public String staticUrl="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";

public Movie(Integer id, String title, String overView, String releaseDate, Integer voteCount,
             String imagePath, Boolean adult, Boolean video, List<Integer> genreIds, Double voteAverage,
             Double popularity, String originalLanguage, String originalTitle, String backdropPath) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.overView = overView;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.voteCount = voteCount;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.adult = adult;
    this.video = video;
    this.genreIds = genreIds;
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    this.popularity = popularity;
    this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}




public Boolean getAdult() {
    return adult;
}

public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
    this.adult = adult;
}

public Boolean getVideo() {
    return video;
}

public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
    this.video = video;
}

public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
    return genreIds;
}

public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
    this.genreIds = genreIds;
}

public Double getVoteAverage() {
    return voteAverage;
}

public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}

public Double getPopularity() {
    return popularity;
}

public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
    this.popularity = popularity;
}

public String getOriginalLanguage() {
    return originalLanguage;
}

public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
    this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
}

public String getOriginalTitle() {
    return originalTitle;
}

public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
    this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
}

public String getBackdropPath() {
    return backdropPath;
}

public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}





public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getOverView() {
    return overView;
}

public void setOverView(String overView) {
    this.overView = overView;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public int getVoteCount() {
    return voteCount;
}

public void setVoteCount(int voteCount) {
    this.voteCount = voteCount;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
```

}

```
public class MovieGetting {

@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private int page;
@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Movie> results;
@SerializedName("total_results")
@Expose
private int totalResults;
@SerializedName("total_pages")
@Expose
private int totalPages;



public int getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(int page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public List<Movie> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Movie> results) {
    this.results = results;
}

public int getTotalResults() {
    return totalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(int totalResults) {
    this.totalResults = totalResults;
}

public int getTotalPages() {
    return totalPages;
}

public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
    this.totalPages = totalPages;
}
```

}
**THIS MY ERRORS**

```
E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/AkJQpZp9WoNdj7pLYSj1L0RcMMN.jpg
```

E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: No content provider: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/AkJQpZp9WoNdj7pLYSj1L0RcMMN.jpg
                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/AkJQpZp9WoNdj7pLYSj1L0RcMMN.jpg
                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1435)
                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1286)
                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1006)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.(Unknown Source:156)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source:13)
                        at com.example.enes.cinemaapp.MyMovieAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(MyMovieAdapter.java:110)
                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25883)
                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Comment: Please add you code as text rather than a screen shot it will make people creating answers much easier. Are you getting any errors returned from firebase?

Comment: Yes,I added my code and errors thanl you

Comment: Okey I solved that problem.Anyone that wants to learn solving can write comment here and I can help him

Comment: Are you able to create an answer for your own question. It may help users in the future.